# Updating different products with different prices without any loop

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, product-collection

i am updating different products with different prices of a specific store. Everything is working fine. But problem is, it takes too much time as i have 1000 of products.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addStoreFilter($_primarystoreid)->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $prod1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($_primarystoreid);
    $prod2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($_secondarystoreid);

    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $prod1->load($product->getId());
        $actualPrice = $prod1->getPrice();
        $newPrice = ((((float) $price) / 100) * $actualPrice) + $actualPrice;
        $prod2->load($product->getId());
        $prod2->setPrice($newPrice)->getResource()->saveAttribute($prod2, 'price');
    }
```

So is there any way to do the same thing without any loop?Thank You

Comment: just to understand...what is the value of `$price` variable. It's not defined anywhere.

Comment: $price is just a variable. In my case, its value is 20 suppose.

Comment: is it the same for all the products or varies from product to product?

Comment: What I understand from your code is that you want to increase the prices for a specific store with 20%. Am I right?

Comment: yes..exactly. But it takes a lot of time.

Comment: See my updated answer. It doesn't get any faster than that.

Comment: Thanks..let me try.
i will get back to you soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have 2 `load` calls in your loop. I think that's the expensive part not the loop itself.
Second...I don't understand where does `$price` come from.
But anyway...Here is an approach that uses a loop but does not call load.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addStoreFilter($_primarystoreid)->addAttributeToSelect('price');

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
        array($product->getId()), //what products to update
        array('price' => your price formula here), //what attributes to update
        $_secondarystoreid //on what store
    )

}
```

Even if the loop still exists, this is definitely faster.

**[EDIT]**
If you want fast, you can take the risky sql way.
Just write a query that will update everything. It does not get any faster than that.
Here is the idea.
First you have to get the id of the price attribute:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'price';
```

All the prices are kept in the `catalog_product_entity_decimal` table.
So you need to do this...
Get all the prices for products where store_id is 'primary store id'.
There is a chance that some of the products have for price "use default", and there is no record with `store_id` = {primary store id}.  In this case you need the values for the product where `store_id = 0`.
Now multiply this value with 1.2 (increase with 20%) and insert the values for the same products but with `store_id = {secondary store Id}`.
But there is a chance that there is such a record for a product. In this case you cannot insert a new line because of the unique constraints. You just have to update the value.
Simple huh? :)

Here is what I came up with. But please backup your db before trying anything. I won't be held responsible if something goes south.

Replace the palceholders with your values.

```
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_decimal (entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)
(
SELECT 
    e.entity_type_id, 
    e.attribute_id, 
    {secondary store id} as store_id, 
    e.entity_id, 
    IFNULL(e1.value, e.value) * 1.2 as value 
FROM 
    catalog_product_entity_decimal e
LEFT JOIN 
    catalog_product_entity_decimal e1 
ON 
    e.attribute_id = e1.attribute_id AND
    e1.store_id = {primary store id} AND
    e.entity_id = e1.entity_id
WHERE 
    e.attribute_id = {price attribute id} AND 
    e.store_id = 0
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    value = IFNULL(e1.value, e.value) * 1.2
```

When you are done, reindex everything.

Comment: It is showing me an error. Could you please double check your answer? thankyou

Comment: it worked for me. Can you tell me what error you get?

Comment: There has been an error processing your request.

Comment: $write = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection("core_write");
$query="query goes here";
$write->query($query);
am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Oh. I didn't try it in the code. I just executed the query on the db. Check var/log for the error message.